# How to retrieve user's Youtube Playlist by YouTube API?

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am building an app for users to manage their own playlists and channels,

I use AccountPicker to get auth token,

the question is how can I get the user's playlist by YouTube API ?

I have read the [YouTube Developer Document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/), and try many ways to get it,

but all failed,

Is there any way for me to get user's playlist by AccountPicker ?

Could somebody show me the exactly workflow ?

Thanks...

Comment: it's my workflow...
1. Use AccountPicker to pick the account to log in.
2. Use the GoogleAuthUtil to get auth token, the scope is :
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
3. send request to get user's playlist :
   "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&mine=true&key=" + authToken;

Answer (score 0):

All the information you need is given [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists#Retrieving_playlists).

Comment: it's my workflow...
1. Use AccountPicker to pick the account to log in.
2. Use the GoogleAuthUtil to get auth token, the scope is :
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
3. send request to get user's playlist :
   "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&mine=true&key=" + authToken;